# Do all filters of infinite sets on $\mathbb{N}$ have this special "omnipresent" set?

Tags: general-topology, filters

If $F$ is a filter on $\mathbb{N}$ such that every set in it is infinite, then does there exist an infinite set $X$ such that every set $A\in F$ misses only finitely many elements of $X$, i.e. $X\setminus A$ is finite?

**Related question:** In such filter $F$ on $\mathbb{N}$, does there exist a subset $C$ of $F$ that is a chain (totally ordered), such that every set from the filter is a superset of some set from $C$?

**Motivation:** This is a translation of "does there exist a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ such that every set of the filter contains some tail of this sequence?". Motivation was that if a countable set can "come arbitrarily close" to some point $p$ in some topological space, but it doesn't contain that point $p$, then there exists a sequence within that countable set that converges to $p$. Assuming some axioms of countability this is true, but I wonder if the condition I gave is enough.

**Why I believe it could be true:** I know that there may exist an uncountably long chain (ordered by $\subset$) of sets from this family, but I also know that if you can embed an ordinal in $\mathbb{R}$ then that ordinal is countable. Then this chain can be extended by intersections of all bounded subchains making it an extension of some ordinal (in some sense). Then I just need some bond between this chain and $\mathbb{R}$ which I *can* find, but then I can't find a chain which "goes through" the whole filter (that's this "related question"). Something is always missing...

Comment: @MarkSaving You're right, thanks. I did edit it to add exactly that, that $X$ should be infinite too.

Comment: Every nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$  is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is an ultrafilter, then your conjectured property certainly does not hold: Whenever $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb N$, either $Y=\{x_2,x_4,,x_6,\ldots\}$ or it’s complement $Y^\complement$ is in $F$, and both $X\setminus Y$ and $X\setminus Y^\complement$ are infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

Let $F$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter. Then all elements of $F$ are infinite.

Now suppose there were such an $X$. Since $X$ is infinite, we can write $X = Y \cup Z$ for disjoint infinite sets $Y, Z$. Clearly, neither $Y$ nor $Z$ can be an element of $F$, since $Y = X \setminus Z$ and $Z = X \setminus Y$ are both infinite. Therefore, since $F$ is an ultrafilter, $X = Y \cup Z \notin F$, and thus $W = \mathbb{N} \setminus X$ is in $F$. But $X \setminus W = X$ is infinite; contradiction.