# Does the cocountable filter have a totally ordered base?

Tags: analysis, set-theory, filters

I was wondering what are the filters that have a totally ordered base, i.e. there is a chain $L$ of sets from the filter $F$ such that $(\forall A\in F)(\exists B\in L)B\subseteq A$?

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588076) question I sensed that some ultrafilters can't have such a base. Then I wanted to work on some concrete example and try to prove or disprove its existance, but I failed as hard as in the linked question. This concrete example (below) is not (necessarily) an ultrafilter and I thought it would be richer to work with than on countable sets, but it wasn't the case...

**Concrete question:** Given the family $F$ of cocountable subsets of an uncountable set $X$, does there exist a totally ordered subfamily $G$ of $F$ such that $(\forall A\in F)(\exists B\in G)B\subseteq A$?

**Progress so far:** I did prove that such subfamily exists for the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ (which should be the same as $\aleph_1$, but I don't know cardinals). But does such a base exist for example in the case $X=\mathbb{R}$ or $X=\aleph_2$?

EDIT: The question is seemingly answered in the comments: Assuming the axiom of choice (namely $DC_{\omega_1}$) we have that $X$ has this property if and only if $|X|=\aleph_1$.

Comment: If the filter of cocountable subsets of an uncountable set $X$ has a totally ordered base, then $|X|=\aleph_1$. This is because the union of a chain of countable sets has cardinality at most $\aleph_1$. So $\aleph_2$ is out. As for $\mathbb R$ that depends on whether the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is equal to $\aleph_1$ or greater, the famous continuum problem.

Comment: @bof Thank you for confirming the result. edit: I even understand what you said now. Thanks!

Comment: @bof Actually, could you please give me a hint on why the union of a chain of countable sets is at most $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @bof I proved it, but I used the axiom of dependent choice. Perhaps it's not needed?

Comment: You could not have used only DC, since it is consistent with DC that there is a set which is the union of a chain of countable sets, but it is not well-orderable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh right. I did indeed firstly order it. Thank you for pointing it out. But still, either $DC_{\omega_1}$ or $DC_{\omega_2}$ should be sufficient, I can't believe that the full power of AC is needed.

Comment: Again, ordering is not the issue. Yes, $\sf DC_{\omega_1}$ would suffice here. But that wasn't what you're asking, is it? You're asking a question, that seemingly, without particular context, is asked in ZFC, not in ZF or some intermediate theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are right, I should be more careful when discussing the need for AC. I recently started to consistently wonder if what I am doing requires AC or some weaker form of it. Also, you are right that my question is not about choice, but since I got this habit I had to ask myself... About ordering, to be exact, I was embedding ordinals into that chain of countable sets. That's where I needed some choice - to pick the next set, I wasn't really ordering the whole chain.